# Portfolio images loading on top of each other on initial load

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, jquery-isotope

Being more UX designer than developer I'm hoping that someone could help me on here with an issue i'm having on a site design. I've created a site on the following address:

www.imaginationcreation.co.uk/website2

On the initial load if you click portfolio or scroll down to that section you will see that the portfolio images are stacked on top of each other and are overlapping into the next section; from what I can tell its just the image stacking which is causing the overlapping issue and once corrected it should all be ok; however i cannot find the solution to the image stacking

Can anyone help me; I can provide files if required

attached is a screenshot on initial page loading (see[on initial load.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0iFQ.jpg) and a screenshots after refreshing the page [after page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhaHL.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: i can't find anything overlapping , could you take a screenshot?

Comment: Hi Victor I have added 2 screenshots to original post

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using this plugin for the portfolio section.
http://yiotis.net/filterizr/

**in your jscode** (where init the filterizr), i found some wrong characters ������
 http://www.imaginationcreation.co.uk/website2/assets/js/function.js

```
var workfilter = $('.work-masonry');
    workfilter.filterizr({
    ������//your options here
      layout: 'packed',
    });

    $('.filters-group li .filter').on('click', function() {
      $('.filters-group li .filter').removeClass('is-checked');
      $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    });

});
```

Fix it as:

```
var workfilter = $('.work-masonry');
    workfilter.filterizr({
    //your options here
         layout: 'packed',
    });

    $('.filters-group li .filter').on('click', function() {
      $('.filters-group li .filter').removeClass('is-checked');
        $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    });

});
```

Maybe this cause the problem, make a try if problem still exist, please feedback for me later.

---

**20180727 Updates..** .

It seems if $('.filters-group li .filter').onClick then the filterizr shows well. So, lets trigger click events when the pageLoad at first!

Try update to:

```
var workfilter = $('.work-masonry');
    workfilter.filterizr({
    //your options here
         layout: 'packed',
    });

    $('.filters-group li .filter').on('click', function() {
      $('.filters-group li .filter').removeClass('is-checked');
        $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    });

    // trigger click event at first
    var e = $.Event('click');
    $('.filters-group li .filter').trigger(e);
});
```

Make a try..

---

**20180727-v2 Updates**

Hello again, I found that it's because of the images not loaded completely that caused the filterizr.js can't define the height of `img` inside each `.work-item`.

So, what we should do is make sure all images load successfully then active the filterizr.js plugins...

**Update the code below:**

```
// 04.3 Portfolio Filterizr
//================================================================================
var workfilter = $('.work-masonry');
var perItem = $('.work-masonry .work-item');

/* Here test before filterizr plugin active, if images load completely or not (value = 0, means imgs not loaded) */
console.log('Test if images load completely or not!! item Height::', perItem.height());

var activeFilterizr = function() {
    workfilter.filterizr({
        //your options here
        layout: 'packed',
    });

    /* Here test after images load successfully and filterizr.js plugin active (value should be correct number) */
    console.log('When Images Ready!! item Height::', perItem.height());

    /* The $('.filters-group li .filter') seems not in the index.html you gave me so i comment out the code below */
    // $('.filters-group li .filter').on('click', function() {
    //   domFilter.removeClass('is-checked');
    //     $(this).addClass('is-checked');
    // });
}

//window preload images events
function imageLoadEvent(activeFilterizr) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = activeFilterizr;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            /* Make sure images load successfully then active the filterizr.js plugin */
            activeFilterizr();
        }
    }
}
//Start preload event
imageLoadEvent(activeFilterizr);
// 04.3 Portfolio Filterizr End
```

I wrote the console.log() to check the height of `img`, if loaded unCompletely you will see below in browser's console:

```
'Test if images load completely or not!! item Height::' 0
```

Nevertheless, imageLoadEvent function helps you preloading all images then start filterizr.js otherwise it will never be started untill images ready!

```
'When Images Ready!! item Height::' 267
```

By the way, the reason why first time load the page overlapping is because of clean browser cahce which spend much more time for loading images. That's why the issue happened.

Comment: Hi unfortunately it didnt correct it; i replaced the code with your version and it still appears the same

Comment: Hi; unfortunately it didnt work and appears the same as before; however this time its effected the filters by selecting the third one along from the left; I have left that file uploaded for you to be able to see what I mean

Comment: Could you send me the files so i can test in localhost if u argee.

Comment: yes sure; no problem; I really appreciate your help with this; I will send them now

Comment: I have sent them to your gmail as I couldn't send them on here

Comment: gmail kept blocking the attachment so have sent it to you by mailbigfile

Comment: I have received, tks

Comment: Hi Jamie,  I have updated my answer. I think it's the solution

Comment: Hi Victor; thank you so much for this however I updated the code in the function.js as you said with the above but it seems to be causing a syntax error on line 446 which strangely is the end line of the code

Comment: Like I said before I'm a UX designer rather than developer so I apologise in advance if its something that I'm not doing correctly

Comment: Hi jamie, i send the files i fixed to your gmail, plz check it out